# Please, explain the following example for: ++i vs i++ in 'for' loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, post-increment

(I'm currently learning C++) For most problems, `++i` & `i++` show no difference in `for` loop [i.e. `for ( i = 1 ; i < 6 ; ++i )` vs `for ( i = 1 ; i < 6; i++ )`]. So, I asked ChatGPT for an example in which both differ in output. I did get a good example, but I didn't understand how the output was obtained (the `i++` version). Code is given below:

```
int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    cout << "Using pre-increment (++i):" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
        ++arr[i]; // Increment the array element
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Using post-increment (i++):" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
        ++arr[i]; // Increment the array element
    }
    cout << endl;
```

Output received:

```
Using pre-increment (++i):
1 2 3 4 5
Using post-increment (i++):
2 3 4 5 6
```

Can anyone explain, how the output is different?

I tried the code and obtained same result. But, I didn't understand how the `i++` version got different result. I thought `i` is updated after printing the `arr[i]`(which is, `arr[0] = 1`). Also, `++arr[i]` is in the next line, so it shouldn't affect `cout` in the above line.
I asked ChatGPT to explain. Below is an extract from it's answer:

**Using post-increment (i++):**
*Loop Iteration 1 (i = 0):*

- The value of arr[0] is 2. // how?
- 2 is printed.
- arr[0] is incremented to 3

Comment: In that context there's no difference, the compiler will likely generate the exact same code for both.

Comment: `Can anyone explain, how the output is different?`: because your second loop acts on the values in `arr` that have already been modified by the first loop :-)

Comment: What is the purpose of `++arr[i]`? What is your assignment or exercise?

Comment: And as a beginner that tries to learn C++, please stay away from so-called "AI" bots like ChatGPT. Learn the basics using [good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and classes. AI bots tend to copy-paste different snippets with no real knowledge, often containing subtle errors or problems, which are hard to find for a beginner. It also take lots of attempts to get something good from the bots, and you need to refine the prompts, and provide feedback on things that are wrong in its replies.

Comment: *So, I asked chatgpt for an example in which both differ in output.* -- And Chatgpt gave you a bogus example.  You have altered the array when the second `for` loop is invoked.

Comment: If the AI bot were smart enough, [this should have been the example](https://godbolt.org/z/63hfcTMax), showing that it isn't possible.  Instead the bot got all confused, so much so that the second `for` loop still had the pre-increment being done on `arr`.

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you You cleared my doubt. Now I understand, This was a foolish question, But I'm glad that I started this account & asked it. I will delete this post soon. Once again, thank you for quick reply

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would say stay away from chatGPT in general (if you want to learn something).  ChatGPT doesn't know "C" from "C++" anyway. The thing about AI's is they give answers that "Seem reasonable" which might or might not be good enough for "human" questions but it will be utterly *^%@$! for anything exact like a computer program (or math).

Comment: Some good resources to learn C++ from are [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) for your initial steps (it is very decent for an online tutorial). 
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to lookup everything C++ has to offer. 
And finally use the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with how C++ evolves and how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: If we want to be really crazy, since this is C++: `for (auto &x : arr) { cout << x << endl; x++; }`